# CUDA texture can't return value type of unsigned long long

Tags: c++, cuda, textures

I have code :

```
#define int4 unsigned long long int
int4 mer_thread = tex2D(STexture, col, row);
printf("\nTexture[%d][%d] = %d", row, col, tex2D(STexture, col, row));
```

Error "error : no instance of overloaded function "tex2D" matches the argument list"

but if `define int4 unsigned long int`, it work fine.

My code creat texture:

```
void Creat_TexttureS(int4 _S[nmax][NMAX])
{
    cudaArray* carray;
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channel;      
    channel = cudaCreateChannelDesc<int4>();        
    cudaMallocArray(&carray, &channel, NMAX, nmax);    
    cudaMemcpyToArray(carray, 0, 0, _S, sizeof(int4)*NMAX*nmax, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);  
    STexture.filterMode = cudaFilterModePoint;      
    STexture.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    STexture.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeClamp;     
    cudaBindTextureToArray(STexture, carray);
}
```

Thanks for your help !!

Comment: The hardware does not support textures with base types wider than 32 bits. If you just need textures for storage, you could use `int2` to store 64-bit data types such as `double`, `long long int`, `unsigned long long int`. You can then assemble the wider type from the pair of 32-bit words after the texture read, in case of `double` use `__hiloint2double()` for this, or `__byte_perm()` in the case of `unsigned long long int`.

Comment: Sorry I mispoke, `__byte_perm()` really isn't the right approach, we want simple re-interpretation of the `int2` as a `long long int`. Try this: `__forceinline__ __device__ long long int int2_as_longlong (int2 a) { long long int res; asm ("mov.b64 %0, {%1,%2};" : "=l"(res) : "r"(a.x), "r"(a.y)); return res; }`

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you help me apply it to my code or make a example about it, i don't understand how to use it, where it used ?

Comment: I apply your code but it still has error the same i post. My code :

int2 valtext = tex2D(STexture, col, row);
long long int b = int2_as_longlong(valtext);

Comment: The problem would appear to be your texture declaration then, which I don't see in the code you posted. I would suggest starting with something simple like `texture<int2, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a worked example that demonstrates the storing of data of type `long long int` in a 2D texture of type `int2`, then how to retrieve it via `tex2D()` and re-interpret it as `long long int`.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Macro to catch CUDA errors in CUDA runtime calls
#define CUDA_SAFE_CALL(call)                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    cudaError_t err = call;                                           \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)
// Macro to catch CUDA errors in kernel launches
#define CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR()                                          \
do {                                                                  \
    /* Check synchronous errors, i.e. pre-launch */                   \
    cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();                             \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString(err) );       \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
    /* Check asynchronous errors, i.e. kernel failed (ULF) */         \
    err = cudaThreadSynchronize();                                    \
    if (cudaSuccess != err) {                                         \
        fprintf (stderr, "Cuda error in file '%s' in line %i : %s.\n",\
                 __FILE__, __LINE__, cudaGetErrorString( err) );      \
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                           \
    }                                                                 \
} while (0)

__forceinline__ __device__ long long int int2_as_longlong (int2 a)
{
    long long int res;
    asm ("mov.b64 %0, {%1,%2};" : "=l"(res) : "r"(a.x), "r"(a.y));
    return res;
}

texture<int2, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;

__global__ void kernel (int m, int n) 
{
    int2 data;
    for (int row = 0; row < m; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < n; col++) {
            data = tex2D (tex, col, row);
            printf ("% 11lld  ", int2_as_longlong (data));
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    int m = 4; // height = #rows
    int n = 3; // width  = #columns
    size_t pitch, tex_ofs;
    unsigned long long int arr[4][3]= 
        {{11111111LL, 11112222LL, 11113333LL},
         {22221111LL, 22222222LL, 22223333LL},
         {33331111LL, 33332222LL, 33333333LL},
         {44441111LL, 44442222LL, 44443333LL}};
    int2 *arr_d = 0;

    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMallocPitch((void**)&arr_d,&pitch,n*sizeof(*arr_d),m));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMemcpy2D(arr_d, pitch, arr, n*sizeof(arr[0][0]),
                                n*sizeof(arr[0][0]),m,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaBindTexture2D (&tex_ofs, &tex, arr_d, &tex.channelDesc,
                                       n, m, pitch));
    if (tex_ofs !=0) {
        printf ("tex_ofs = %zu\n", tex_ofs);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf ("printing texture content\n");
    kernel<<<1,1>>>(m, n);
    CHECK_LAUNCH_ERROR();
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaUnbindTexture (tex));
    CUDA_SAFE_CALL (cudaFree (arr_d));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```